# When given an Object with two sibling properties, using jq how do I create a new Object where the sibling property is moved to be a child property?

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of Objects in the following form:

```
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": "gamma",
        "delta": "epsilon"
    },
    "zeta": {
        "eta": "theta",
        "iota": "kappa"
    }
}
```

Using `jq`, I would like to transform this Object to be in the following form:

```
{
    "alpha": {
        "beta": "gamma",
        "delta": "epsilon",
        "zeta": {
            "eta": "theta",
            "iota": "kappa"
        }
    },
}
```

How do I do that? I'm not especially familiar with `jq's` syntax and the manual isn't presenting any clear answers, at least as far as I can see.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ jq '{alpha: (.alpha + {zeta})}' tmp.json
{
  "alpha": {
    "beta": "gamma",
    "delta": "epsilon",
    "zeta": {
      "eta": "theta",
      "iota": "kappa"
    }
  }
}
```

`{zeta}` is shorthand for `{zeta: .zeta}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [assignment](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment) to add the zeta field where you want it, and [`del`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#del(path_expression)) to remove it where you don't want it anymore.

```
jq '.alpha.zeta=.zeta|del(.zeta)' input.json
```